# When I click on back button dataTable is not displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

Currently I use Jquery dataTable in .NET MVC. When I select something from drop down list and click on search button then it display records in dataTable format. There is one column in dataTable named as detail. When I click on that link it redirects to another page which display detail information of that particular record. But when I go back it will not display dataTable with records and not dataTable also.

This is search view:

```
<div id="search-structure">
        </div>
</div>
</div>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        addrSearchButtonClickHandler();
    });
    function addrSearchButtonClickHandler() {
        $(document).off("click", "#Search-by-obsolescence").on("click", "#Search-by-obsolescence", function () {
            var build_Type = $("#residenceType").val();
            var quality = $("#Quality").val();
            var style = $("#firstStyle").val();
            if (build_Type == null || build_Type == '') {
                displayErrorMessage("Select Building Type value");
                return false;
            }
            if (quality == null || quality == '') {
                displayErrorMessage("Select Quality value.");
                return false;
            }
            if (style == null || style == '') {
                displayErrorMessage("Select Style value.");
                return false;
            }
            var data = { 'build_Type': build_Type, 'quality': quality, 'style': style };
            var Url = "@Url.Content("~")Assessment/AssessmentSearchResultByFunctionalObsolescence";
            BlockUI();
           // $("#search-structure").removeClass("hide");
            $.get(Url, data, function (result) {
                UnblockUI();
                $("#search-structure").html(result);
              //  $("#search-structure").addClass("show");
            });
        });
    }
</script>
```

And this is another view for dataTable:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var imgstr = '<img src="@Url.Content("~")Content/Images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Please Wait..."/>'
        $(".dataTables_processing").html(imgstr);
        clearCookie('current_tab');
        if ('@Model' == null || '@Model.Count()' == 0 || '@Model.Count()' == 1) {
            clearCookie('filterData');
        }
          var columnIndexes = [7];
          makeDataTablesortdisb("dataTable-search-by-Function-Obsolescence", columnIndexes);
        var oTable = $('#dataTable-search-by-Function-Obsolescence').dataTable();
        $('#dataTable-search-by-Function-Obsolescence').on('draw.dt', function () {
            disableSortingSearchOption(oTable, 'dataTables_filter input');
        });
        $(".dataTables_filter input").after('<img id="grid-search-refresh-button" tabindex="0"class="search-icon" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/search-refresh-button-icon.png")" width="28" alt="search" title ="Refresh" style="float: right; position: relative; top: -3px; cursor:pointer;" />');
       $("div.dataTables_filter #grid-search-refresh-button").click(function (e) {
        $(this).addClass("outline-none");
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#search-error-text").remove();
            $("div.dataTables_filter select option").first().attr('selected', true);
            oTable.fnFilter('');
      });
       DetailClickHandler();
       $("#SearchByFunObsolescenceReportPrint").click(function () {
            var url = "@Url.Content("~")Reports/ReportViewer/Search_Result_By_Address.aspx";
            window.location.href = url;
        });
    });
    function DetailClickHandler() {
        $(document).on("click", "#detail", function (e) {
            BlockUI();
            e.preventDefault();
            var parcel_no = $(this).attr("parcel_no");
            var assessment_no = $(this).attr("assessment_no");
            var url = "@Url.Content("~")Assessment/Assessment?parcel_no=" + parcel_no + "&assesmt_no=" + assessment_no;
            window.location.href = url;
        });
    }
</script>
```

But I think for above problem only need to change first view. Then what is solution for that ???

Comment: Take a look to the bStateSave http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/features.
for the new version is  stateSave.

Comment: I use bStateSave property also but nothing work